# REST API - "AND" Clause not working

Tags: rest-api

I am attempting to run a REST API Query against my org. The following query selects all of the fields from 'Account' where the name equals a string and the record type equals a specific record type. However, every time I add the word "AND" it is failing with a "bad message 400" "unknown version".

Here is the query...

```
SELECT+Id+FROM+Account+WHERE+Name='SHOP'+AND+RecordType.Name=+'Property'
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Edit:
Full URL

```
https://my_org_name.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Account+WHERE+Name='SHOP'+AND+RecordType.Name='Property'
```

Comment: Your post would be much easier to read if you remove all fields from your `SELECT` clause except `Id`.

Comment: No need to + before and after '='. Remove and retry, should work

Comment: Nope... doesn't work

Comment: What's the full URL you're using to call this API

Comment: Can you make sure if that recordtype name exists in Account object? Or/AND make sure you have an account with name 'Shop'. I do not see any issue at all with the query.. i tried with similar query and did not get any error at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:
First: The single quotes must be URL encoded. The URL code for a single quote is %27
so like this:

```
https://my_org_name.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Account+WHERE+Name=%27SHOP%27+AND+RecordType.Name=%27Property%27
```

Second: The dot in **RecordType.Name** is most likely the root of the problem. Normally you should not use a dot in the URI parameters. You can try encoding the dot with **%2E** or use the encoding utility to encode the whole query string:

```
String qStr = 'https://my_org_name.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/query/?q=SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name=\'SHOP\' AND RecordType.Name=\'Property\'";
String encodedqStr= EncodingUtil.urlEncode(qStr, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: `/services/data/v45.0/query/?q=[SOQL query]` is part of the [standard REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm), and so the developer does not have the ability to change how it works. The SO post you referenced is about having a resource represented by a single period, not about an inability to ever have periods in valid URLs ever. The whole query needs to be URL encoded, but that's it.

Comment: Oh interesting I wasn't aware SOQL queries are supported as URI params. Then perhaps encoding the URL may work.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear if you are actually able to save it without the escape character `\`. It should actually not even compile and save. However, I just checked below in my org and its working:

```
req.setEndpoint('https://my_org_name.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Account+WHERE+Name=\'SHOP\'+AND+RecordType.Name=\'Property\'');
```

Note: Ofcourse `my_org_name` is changed to my domain.